# Is there a way to have multiple applications reference a global project that has other project references

Tags: c#, project-reference

After searching quite a bit, I seem to be unable to find an answer to my problem. Usually, I find that means it is a non existent or incorrect approach, but I think it worth it to have an answer floating around on the internet nonetheless.

Essentially, we have 4 applications referencing 5 different "source" projects. So the scenario is, when we add a 5th application (for example), we will need to create project references to the other 5 different projects, as the application requires their output.

Its not a difficult task because the amount of projects is small, but it got us thinking. What if you could create a single project, maybe called Libs or something, reference all 5 projects in that project, and then the applications must only reference Libs. The idea seems cool, but I don't know if it will work because when you create a project reference, it points to Libs single output libs.dll.

So to actually ask a question, is this possible, and if so, how can it be done? Currently, having Libs reference the other "source" projects, and then having the applications reference the Lib project does not work, as it says there are missing assemblies.

And just to go over how this was created. The 5 source projects reside in a couple different solutions, so the only tedious part of this approach is "add existing project" at the initial start of the application's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way we manage this kind of thing in my organisation is to make a NuGet package for each of these shared "source" projects (e.g. in our case we have an error logging library, an XML utils library, a bespoke HTTP client, and others). These are published to our private NuGet feed URL (hosted on Azure DevOps, but you can just use a standard Windows fileshare if necessary) for our developers to use in their applications.

This has some clear advantages over your approach:

1) Dependencies - this seems most relevant to your question. If the project you built the NuGet package from itself depends on any other NuGet packages (either publicly available ones, or others from our private feed) then when someone installs that package in their project it will automatically install all the other packages it depends on.

So in your case you could create a shell "libs" package which doesn't deliver any content itself, but has dependencies on all your other packages, causing them to be installed automatically. In our case we have several cases of dependency (e.g. a "base" error logging package which is relied on by error handling modules which are tailored to different app types, e.g. MVC, Web API, Windows Services), and it works very well.

2) Updates and maintenance. In your scenario if you make a breaking change to one of your "source" projects, then, because you have a direct project reference declared in Visual Studio, any project which references the source one will have to make related changes to cope with the updates to the source project, before you can re-compile it and do whatever feature changes you're trying to achieve. This could be a pain, and be an untimely problem, especially in the case of major updates. However if instead you install a NuGet package containing that functionality, the developer of the application can choose if and when to install an updated version of the package.

There are other minor benefits as well which I won't go into, but there are some very good reasons why almost all major programming languages now provide similar "package" and "feed" functionality as a way of managing dependency on external projects and libraries. Your approach is, I feel, outdated and naive, resulting in the issue you've described and the potential for other irritations as well.

Comment: beautiful! Any documentation to set that up. Links that worked for you?

Comment: Microsoft (and others) have loads of documentation, tutorials etc about creating NuGet packages, it's been around for years, you can google it easily. This one is probably a good place to start though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package . P.S. If you are creating your libraries targeting .NET Standard or .NET Core (rather than .NET Framework), there are now GUI tools built into Visual Studio which make the process easier. This article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview talks about options for hosting NuGet feeds.